# How to display computed value for a column in vue-table-2

Tags: vue.js

An API to server returns a dataset where date/time is an epoch (`eventTime`) number. I need to translate it to a date/time human readable format. What is the correct format to make the same happen?

Template for displaying table

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   <v-client-table
      :data="tableData"
      :columns="columns"
      :options="options">
   </v-client-table>
</div>
```

JS part

```
data () {
  return {
    User,
    title: 'Verifications',
    columns: ['trackingcode', 'userName', 'eventTime',
      'scanResult', 'place_info.administrative_area_level_1'],
    tableData: [],
    rows: this.tableData,
    options: {
      uniqueKey: '_id',
      headings: {
        trackingcode: 'Serial Num',
        userName: 'User Name',
        dateTime: 'Date/Time',
        scanResult: 'Status',
        'place_info.administrative_area_level_1': 'City'
      },
      columnsDropdown: true,
      filterByColumn: true,
      sortable: ['trackingcode', 'userName'],
      filterable: ['trackingcode', 'userName', 'place_info.administrative_area_level_1']
    }
  }

methods: {
  getHumanDate: function (date) {
    var fixedstring
    try {
      // If the string is UTF-8, this will work and not throw an error.
      fixedstring = decodeURIComponent(escape(date))
    } catch (e) {
      // If it isn't, an error will be thrown, and we can asume that we have an ISO string.
      fixedstring = date
    }
    return moment.unix(fixedstring / 1000).format('DD-MMM-YYYY h:mm:ss A Z')
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the value seconds or milliseconds? In any case, I recommend [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: I already have a function to do that. What I am trying to achieve is how to display the client computed/translated column value for each row.

Comment: updated the functions I have in place. Works fine when no translation is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of this with the js Date object, I don't see where the problem is?

To convert ms-since-epoch to a date object, just feed put it in the constructor... `new Date(1538380103350);` The best place to do this is straight after you receive it, after `JSON.parse()`, or even in a reviver function if this makes sense, but it might be tricky to discern dates in this format from other data.

Then format or translate your Date with all the goodness of `toLocaleDateString()`. Give us more details of the required format, and I'll might have more handy advice :-)

Comment: Maybe my problem example is misleading. I do not need help per-se with formatting date.
I need help in adding a new field/column to the array after the axios/async call has completed. date/time is one such field which needs change before it is displayed in the table. I have other fields which require change from int values to string.
In short, what is the best way to change/manipulate/add data to the data set received?

Comment: Js arrays don't really have columns, they're one dimensional lists of objects. Look at the array methods map() and forEach() for looping through an  array. With your date, as I said, it makes sense to overwrite the timestamp value with a real date object. For other properties, formatting is not a good reason to add a property to the source data! You want to keep the source data "normalised", so there's one unambiguous place to modify it. Then you put all your formatting in Vue computed. Does that help? Show me some source data?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was able to do the same using vue-table-2 rowCallback method. I will though keep the suggested options in mind as well.

Comment: With dates, there are so many tricks at different steps that it helps to have a policy. Our policy is to rehydrate them into Date objects with a reviver function, 2nd argument to JSON.parse(). And to force dates with unspecified timezone to UTC. And to use midnight UTC to represent "just a date". Sticking to these tenets of faith helps us remain sane.

Answer (score 0):

```
   #Html Part ty this it's work for me
    <div id="vue-tables-options" class="container">
      <h2>VueTables 2 Options API</h2>
      <v-client-table :data="data" :columns="columns" :options="options">
      </v-client-table>
    </div>
    #Js Part

Vue.use(VueTables.client, {
  perPage: 25
})

new Vue({
  el: "#vue-tables-options",
  data: {
    columns: ['option', 'type', 'description', 'default','date'],
    data: [
    {
    option:'columnsClasses',
    type:'Object',
    description:'Add class(es) to the specified columns. Takes key-value pairs, where the key is the column name and the value is a string of space-separated classes',
    default:'<code>{}</code>',
    date:"2021-11-01T09:12:26" 
    },
    {
        option:'multiSorting (client-side)',
      type:'Object',
      description:'See docomentation',
      default:'<code>{}</code>',
      date:"2021-11-01T09:12:26"
    },
    {
        option:'serverMultiSorting',
      type:'Boolean',
      description:'Enable multiple columns sorting using Shift + Click on the server component',
      default:'<code>false</code>',
      date:"2021-11-01T09:12:26"
    },
     {
        option:'clientMultiSorting',
      type:'Boolean',
      description:'Enable multiple columns sorting using Shift + Click on the client component',
      default:'<code>true</code>',
      date:"2021-12-01T09:12:26"
    },
    {
        option:'requestAdapter (server-side)',
      type:'Function',
      description:'Set a custom request format',
      default:'<code>function(data) { return data; }</code>',
      date:"2021-11-01T09:12:45"
    },
    {
    option:'saveState',
    type:'Boolean',
    description:'Constantly save table state and reload it each time the component mounts. When setting it to true, use the `name` prop to set an identifier for the table',
    default:'<code>false</code>'
    },
     {
    option:'storage',
    type:'String',
    description:'Which persistance mechanism should be used when saveState is set to true: `local` - localStorage. `session` - sessionStorage',
    default:'<code>local</code>'
    },
     {
    option:'customSorting',
    type:'Object',
    description:'See documentation',
    default:'<code>{}</code>'
    },
      {
    option:'highlightMatches',
    type:'Boolean',
    description:'Highlight matches',
    default:'<code>false</code>'
    },
    {
      option: 'childRow',
      type: 'Function',
      description: 'See documentation',
      default: "<code>false</code>"
    },
     {
      option: 'rowClassCallback',
      type: 'Function',
      description: 'Add dynamic classes to table rows. E.g <pre><code>function(row) {return `row-${row.id}`}</code></pre>This can be useful for manipulating the appearance of rows based on the data they contain',
      default: "<code>false</code>"
    },
      {
      option: 'requestKeys (server-side)',
      type: 'Object',
      description: 'Set your own request keys',
      default: "<pre><code>{<br>query:'query',<br>limit:'limit',<br>orderBy:'orderBy',<br>ascending:'ascending',<br>page:'page',<br>byColumn:'byColumn'<br>}</code></pre>",
      
    },
    {
      option: 'uniqueKey',
      type: 'String',
      description: 'The key of a unique identifier in your dataset, used to track the child rows, and return the original row in row click event',
      default: "<code>id</code>"
    }],
    options: {
      sortable: ['option'],
          dateColumns: ['date'],
          headings:{
          option:"name",
          type:"type",
          description:"dscription",
          default:"default",
          Date:"Date"
          },
       templates: {
        date: function(row) {
          console.log(row.date);
            return moment(String(row.date)).format("MMMM Do YYYY, H:mm:ss");
  },
  },
  }
  }

});
```

Comment: It would be helpful to the OP if you explain what the code is actually doing to achieve the solution.

Comment: sure. it's just a simple thing you have to pass dateColumn name in option as I did `dateColumn: ['date']` and use the same column name in the templates section to fomat the date. you can see the details here also https://matanya.gitbook.io/vue-tables-2/options-api